# Can someone explain me why is this C program compiling without errors?

Tags: c

Hey i am a student learning C programming and just wanted to know that why this program compiles as on line `struct date *newdate, foo();` foo is declared as a function local to main function with the return type struct date. As foo is already declared as a function it should give an error of conflicting types as c does not support function overloading. Can somebody please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

struct date foo(struct date x) {
    ++x.day;

    return x;
};

int main() {
    struct date today = {10, 11, 2014};
    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    struct date *newdate, foo();
    char *string = "test string";
    int i = 3;

    newdate = (struct date *)malloc(sizeof(struct date));
    newdate->month = 11;
    newdate->day = 15;
    newdate->year = 2014;
    today = foo(today);

    free(newdate);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It doesnt produce any errors i just wanted to know why is it not producing errors as on line 19 there is another foo() declaration. :)

Comment: I doesn't produce errors because (IMHO) it is correct.  A declaration can perfectly be followed by an incomplete function declaration (as it is the one in line 19) that doesn't contradict it (by using a different parameter list or return type)  The declaration in line 19 is not `struct date foo(void);` but a declaration of a function with an incomplete (or better, undefined) parameter list. That is not incompatible with the first definition. The complete definition above holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> foo is declared as a function local to main function

Not true.  It declares but does not define that a function `foo` exists, and  that it takes an unknown number of arguments and returns a `struct date`.

This declaration is compatible with the actual definition of `foo`, as the return types match and the declaration makes no statement about the arguments.

Comment: The scope of the `foo` declared in `main` is indeed local to the block of the `main` function, even though it has external linkage and refers to the same function as the previously declared `foo`. I think it might be possible to demonstrate that with different parameter declarations. E.g., one of the declarations might specify a parameter type that is a pointer to an incomplete type that is complete in the other declaration. The one with the incomplete type could be assigned to a pointer to a function with a different complete type, but the complete one could not.